# Request.Form getting values from another user control

Tags: c#, webforms, webusercontrol

I have a page with three user controls on it. Two outputting tables and one holding date inputs.

I'm trying to read the values of the submitted dates using Request.Form["Date1"] etc.  However, I am getting no values.  Am I missing something really basic?

Comment: You should post ur aspx code to get better view of what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write property in your usercontrol

```
public string DateValue
{
    get { return dateValue.Text; }
}
```

If textbox is holding `Date1` above should work or you can change accordingly.

Then just access DateValue wherever you want

In aspx code behind you can create object of user control like below and acces its properties.

```
UserControl userControl = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("userControl");
```

Here `userControl` is the id for `User Control`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where your values are.  ( as long they are under form tag)

The Page submits its forms. I repeat - its forms.

Make sure you are reading the value according to  **The name of the form element**